# Mongoose hooks don't work on macOS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, macos, mongoose

It seems that the [Mongoose hooks](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html) don't work on macOS. No error is shown, but the hooks are simply not triggered.

A minimal example I build is:

```
const Mongoose = require("mongoose");
Mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/test", (err, db) => {

    console.log(err);
    // => undefined
    //    (success)

    // Create the model
    const t = Mongoose.model("t", {
        s: "string"
    });

    // Do something pre save
    t.schema.pre('save', function(next) {
        // This is not triggered
        console.log(">>>>>>>>>>>>>");
        console.log(this);
        next();
    });

    // Insert a new object
    new t({ s: "foo" }).save((err, data) => {
        console.log(err, data);
    });
});
```

Did I make a mistake I dimply don't see or is there anything else that I missed? The pre save is simply not called. Same thing happens for post save.

`save()` should trigger the pre save callback.

How to fix this?

I'm using macOS Sierra. From what I can tell it was working on my Linux machine (which is not here currently).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not running macOS (yet), I am still running OS X El Capitan. I have tested the above code using Mongoose 4.8.1 and it does not work here either. But I noticed you are creating a model and attaching a schema to it after the model was created. It seems to be working when creating a schema, attaching a hook and then initializing the model.

```
// Create the model
var testSchema = new Mongoose.Schema({
    s: "string"
});

// Do something pre save
testSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
    // This is triggered
    console.log(">>>>>>>>>>>>>");
    console.log(this);
    next();
});

// Create model of schema
var testModel = Mongoose.model("Test", testSchema);

// Insert a new object
new testModel({ s: "foo" }).save((err, data) => {
    console.log(err, data);
});
```